# Rhapsody Table View export through report generation issues with semicolons

Tags: xml, report, rhapsody

I'm using Rhapsody 8.2.1, in my project I have a table view containing a cell with a dotted list, each row ending with a semicolon, something like this:

- item 1;
- Item 2;
- ...;
- Item n;

When generating the report through Tools->Publish->Generate Report the entirety of the table is correctly exported, exception made for the cell with the dotted list, which displays only the first item, without the semicolon.

Viewing the exported XML through browser (i.e. interrogating the web server rhapsody opens to generate the report), I noticed that the field DataAsXML under the table view item already had the text cut up to the first semicolon.

Is there a way to avoid Rhapsody stopping on this kind of punctuation, or a way to customize the XML generated by Rhapsody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm I also observe from time to time some issues with the way RPE parses the Rhapsody XML (for example, by very long descriptions to be extracted). The way I found so far and could be applied to your case is:

- separate content from formatting: remove from original table view any special characters (the dot and semicolon, so instead of "dot item1 ;" you have just "item1"). you might loose some formatting in Rhapsody thought, but it will be easier to parse.
- now in RPE template just add formatting: dot + cell content (item1) + semicolon. Note that this template would be an ad hoc template (done for this tableview) and not based in DataAsXML (as this works only with plain representation of tables without fancy formatting, so far I used)

I hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the quick response. I need just a clarification: currently I'm using DataAsXML by parsing it with javascript / regex, to obtain structured data contained in the table view. From your response it is my understanding that there is another way to obtain the table view's data, is this correct? What is it?

P.S. I avoided talking about RPE because I think this is an issue strictly related to how Rhapsody generates the XML: it is the XML itself to be incomplete, RPE in this scenario simply provides me what it found in the data source.

Comment: yes, in this case you need to iterate over your rhapsody model and put the information in the tables you specially prepare in RPE. It means, you have to define table headers and each cell content.  It is kind of "hand picking". I can't upload screenshots here somehow for an example, but this is standard procedure by creating tables in RPE (look for tutorials on the net)

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, this means avoiding Rhapsody's table views completely and replicating that table view's logic inside RPE. That will do, thank you very much.

Comment: yes, correct. however, I just found something that could be useful to you: import rhapsody tableviews as images into RPE. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21959918

Comment: Saw that one, unfortunately I have been asked to avoid images completely, thanks anyway. The table replica in RPE will do the trick.